# Batch file if statement skips over DO statements?

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

So right now what I have is that I am looping through certain files for testing purposes in one folder ("Start") and copying them to another folder using robocopy ("End"). Now in the "End" folder I have different sub-folders as to which I send files depending on what it says in the file name. An example file name would be "9999 SO 04.31.16 R1 NAME" where I look at where it says R1 because of the format of all the files are the same in terms of characters and where it cuts off.

```
    @echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Hello this a test batch file
pause
for %%a in (M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\Start\*.txt) do (
set filename=%%~na
set fileExt=%%~xa
set filePath=%%~pa
set first4=!filename:~15!
set first4=!first4:~0,4! 
set first4=!first4: =!

set fit=!filename:~22!
set fit=!fit:~0,4!
set fit=!fit: =!
set fitFirst4=!filename:~4!
set fitFirst4=!fitFirst4:~0,4!
set fitFirst4=!fitFirst4: =!

echo First4: !first4!
echo FitFirst4: !fitFirst4!


if "!first4!" == "D2" (
    if NOT exist "M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\End\Deployment\"!filename! "vault.txt" (
        robocopy /xc /xn /xo M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\Start M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\End\Deployment "!filename!".txt
    )
)
if "!first4!" == "Pre" (
    if NOT exist "M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\End\Deployment\"!filename! "vault.txt" (
        robocopy /xc /xn /xo M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\Start M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\End\Deployment "!filename!".txt
    )
)
if "!first4!" == "D1" (
    if NOT exist "M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\End\Deployment\"!filename! "vault.txt" (
        robocopy /xc /xn /xo M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\Start M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\End\Deployment "!filename!".txt
    )
)
if "!first4!" == "R1" (
    if NOT exist "M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\End\Deployment\"!filename! "vault.txt" (
        robocopy /xc /xn /xo M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\Start M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\End\Reintegration "!filename!".txt
    )
)
if "!first4!" == "R2" (
    if NOT exist "M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\End\Deployment\"!filename! "vault.txt" (
        robocopy /xc /xn /xo M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\Start M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\End\Reintegration "!filename!".txt
    )
)
if "!first4!" == "R3" (
    if NOT exist "M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\End\Deployment\"!filename! "vault.txt" (
        robocopy /xc /xn /xo M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\Start M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\End\Reintegration "!filename!".txt
    )
)
...
```

Now I rename the files with a certain suffix at the end of where they have been sent to which is why I check if the files exists or not to make sure they do not re-copy the same file again. Now the issue is that when I run the batch file that it will copy some files but not all of them. E.g. in the code I check for "R1", "D2", etc. but only a few get copied where for me right now at the moment only files that have "D2", and "R3" are getting copied but all else are skipped.

I checked my variable !first4! to check if it is getting the values correctly and it is when I print or echo them variable when I run the file. I have only been doing batch for a week now so I am lost as to why the other files are not getting copied and if the "if" statement for checking the files exist or not is incorrect.

Comment: You don't really quote paths and file names like that.  You just put one set of quotes around the whole path including the file name.

Comment: ... like `"M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\End\Deployment\!filename!.txt"`

Comment: Not really understanding why you keep checking if the first4 equals this or that and then reuse the same code to do the same thing no matter what the first4 is.

Comment: I checking first4 because I have to copy the files into different locations depending on what first4 equals.

Comment: Changing what I had to this: "M:\Research\Collaboration\Felipe\End\Deployment\!filename!.txt"  helped out it looks like. Thank you so much!